# Check/Validate textfield can only be from 1 - 80

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I would like to know whats the easiest and simplest way to check/validate my impact textfield that it can only be entered from 1 - 80? My coding is still quite rusty and I tried doing "if (Int(impact.text!) != 1...80)" but it doesn't work.

ViewController

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class TryingOut2Controller: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var impact: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var rigour: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var response: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var total: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        titleLabel.text = postData[myIndex]

        impact.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        rigour.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        response.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc func textChanged() {
        let impactValue = Int(impact.text!)
        let rigourValue = Int(rigour.text!)
        let responseValue = Int(response.text!)
        total.text = String(describing:
            (impactValue ?? 0) + (rigourValue ?? 0) + (responseValue ?? 0)
        )
    }

    @IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {

        if (Int(impact.text!) != 1...80)
        {
            //create alert
        }
        else {

        }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to prevent input or do you want to prevent validation ?

Comment: ( I think using a picker view is the best solution here anyway )

Comment: have you tried using the "valueChanged" event of UITextField?

Comment: Yep. or for all inputs greater than 80, he can automatically change the value to 80, which I think also makes sense

Comment: @CZ54 prevent input of anything that is not 1 - 80

Comment: @AceRivera no i haven't tried valuechanged and i also don't really know how to use that hahaha, i think 1-80 will just do because thats what my boss wants :(

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to implement the delegate function `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` ( see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield )

You can implement this to check if the current value plus the new input could be converted into Int, and is contain by 1...80.

Comment: you are checking value that starts from "9" what if the user types '9' ?? 
Your code won't give the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the reference :). it helps

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to add a action method "editing changed" to your textField:
and check if your textfield do have a value greater than 80

```
   @IBAction func valueChange(_ sender: Any) {
          if let number = Int(self.impact.text!){
               if number > 80 || number < 0 {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter a Valid Number", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(alertAction)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
               }
          }
     }
```

[image]

Comment: so it's smth like that? https://ibb.co/ex8NP6 sorry my swift is quite rusty

Comment: no, you have created a button action, you have to create a textField event of "editing Chnged" as shown in the screenshot

Comment: Thanks! managed to solve it tgt with some of CZ54 reference as well :)

Answer (score 1):

strings can be compared directly even with alphabets or digits in string. you can compare range as: for example

```
    let value = "90"
    if value > "1" && value < "80" {
        print("in range 1-80")
    } else {
        print("out of range 1-80")
        //create alert in your case
    }
    //prints  out of range 1-80
```

hope that helps...!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    var startString = ""
    if (self.impact.text! = nil)
    {
        startString += self.impact.text!
    }
    startString += string
    var limitNumber = startString.toInt()
    if limitNumber > 80 || limitNumber < 0
    {
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```